# ObjectionJS - Using "page" with "withGraphJoined"

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

I have a situation with `withGraphJoined`

I have three tables `Parent`, `Children` and `Friend`.
Parent has an One-To-Many relationship with Children and an One-To-One relationship with Friend

and now i have a query

```
await Parent.query()
  .withGraphJoined("children")
  .orderBy("friend.order")
  .page(1, 10)
```

Let's say I only have 1 Parent and it has 5 children.
The query returns 5 for the total count.
However, the total should be 1 because I only have 1 Parent.
I know if I use `page` with withGraphJoined the paging will be incorrect,
but if I use withGraphFetched I will have an error saying `missing FROM-clause entry for table "friend"`

What should I do if I really need to use page and order by friend?

Comment: Have you found any workaround?